# Typeorm Many to Many relation

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nest, nestjs-typeorm

I have this two entity(Cohort and User)

```
export class Cohort {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.cohortsPupil)
  @JoinTable()
  pupils: User[]
}
```

```
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Cohort, (cohort) => cohort.pupils)
  cohortsPupil: Cohort[]
}
```

how can update cohort.pupils ?

```
const cohort = await this.queryOneByOption({
  relations: ['pupils'],
  where: { id },
});

cohort.pupils = pupilUpdate.pupils;

await this.save(cohort);
```

I use this code and it worked a week ago but now when a pupil has had a relationship before, it gives this error
ERROR: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*******'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.cohort_pupils_user'. The duplicate key value is (A, B)

so now I do:

```
    await this.dataSource.transaction(async (entityManager: EntityManager) => {
      await entityManager.save(Cohort, {
        id,
        pupils: [],
      });

      await entityManager.save(Cohort, {
        id,
        pupils: pupilUpdate.pupils,
      });
    });
```

Can you tell me how you do this operation and whether this error is normal or not?

Comment: your implementation is currect and i don't see any problem in it, I think the problem should be in your ```pupilUpdate.pupils``` and there should be a user with twice reapetation and it cause a problem of inserting a record in ```cohort_pupils_user``` join table with same composite primary key.